# django FilterView shows duplicated filter in template

Tags: python, django

I've got problem with showing filters in my template.
I have view in views.py as follows:

```
class SearchDocView(FilterView):

    template_name = 'searchdoc.html'
    context_object_name = 'founddocs'
    filterset_class = FilterDoc
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(SearchDocView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = FilterDoc(self.request.GET, queryset)
        return queryset
```

I've created my own filter in filters.py:

```
class FilterDoc(django_filters.FilterSet):
    usr_choices=(
        ('foo.user', 'foo.user'),
        ('test.user','test.user'),
        )

    class Meta:
        model=Doc
        fields = ['doc_application_id','doc_client_nip','user_id']

    appid = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='doc_application_id',lookup_expr='icontains')
    nip = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='doc_client_nip',lookup_expr='icontains')
    usrid = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name='user_id', choices=usr_choices)
```

amd my template is:

```
<body>
    <form  method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    {% if founddocs %}
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>DOC APPLICATION ID</td>
                ...
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                {% for doc in founddocs %}{#WZORZEC NAZWA MODELU + '_list'#}
                <td>{{ doc.doc_application_id }}</td>
                ...

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {% else %}
    <p>Nothing to see here!.</p>
    {% endif %}

</body>
```

Filters works perfectly. The problem is every time I load the page I see duplicated filter fields. Like this:
[image]

Why is that? How can I drop duplicates.
Why user have two different widgets. The second one (combobox) is related with id not username. When I try choose something I got "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'test.user'"

Comment: One for the `user_id` in the `fields`, and one for the `usrid` field you defined.

Comment: thx, I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Willem Van Onsem found the problem.
I've replaced fields with fields=[] cause this is nesseccary in Meta class. As to users I've replaced keys to user id according to admin panel
'''

```
usr_choices=(
        (1, 'foo.user'),
        (2, 'test.user'),
        )

    class Meta:
        model=Doc
        fields=[]
```

'''